# Advanced Image cropping and image resizing in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, resize, crop, bitmapdata, smoothing

I have created a image cropping tool in flex using core copyPixel method.

croppedBitmapData.copyPixels(croppedBitmapData, clipCan, new Point(0, 0));

I have to crope area of dementions 20*20 and show this cropped area in an image of demention 250*350.
 Every thing going well.
My problem is image distortion.

Even i am using this method for smoothing image contents on complete.

```
private function smoothImage(event:Event):void
{
    var bitmap: Bitmap = ((event.target as Image).content as Bitmap);
    if (bitmap != null) 
    {
     bitmap.smoothing = true;
    }
}
```

I want to get the result of this site.       http://www.yourplayingcards.com/builder/

Please help me to get ride of image distortion.

```
      Can we show bitmapdata of 20*20 into image of 250*350 without distotion?
```

Comment: I think if you take a 20x20 piece of a bitmap image and expand it to 250x350 you'd have to expect some distortion.  It may be less if you keep the same aspect ratio (250x250 or 350x350), but probably not much.  Image Manipulation in the real world is not like it is on TV, where you can zoom in, sharpen the image, and now 'see' intricate details such as a face reflection in a window which reveals the killer's identity.

Answer (score 1):

What you call 'distortion' is probably what I think you mean by pixelation.  The reason why that website can zoom in without pixelation is because it's using vector shapes, not bitmaps, to show the graphics.  Vector shapes can be scale *infinitely* without loss of quality because it doesn't store pixel information, but spline information.

In essence, if you want to imitate the zooming of the the website you have shown, you will have to create your own vector shape.  You can use [Flex 4's built in FXG format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSda78ed3a750d6b8f26c150d412357de3591-8000.html) or use something like [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/) if you're still in Flex 3.  You can also leverage [Flash Catalyst](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashcatalyst.html) to import vector graphics made in Illustration into Flex.

Comment: How can we convert png or jpg images into vectors in flex 3. Is it possible in Flex 3.?

Comment: This is not a limitation of Flex, but a limitation on the basic principle of how images work.  You can't convert a bitmap image to a vector.  You have to recreate it using illustrator (or some over vector based tool) or you're stuck with bitmaps and the best you can do is enlarge and smooth it, but the quality will be 'meh' at best.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about that but it is done in [VectorMagic](http://hybridhacking.com/node/38) may be they are using server side too any ways, you may also interested in [Actionscript SVG renderer](http://code.google.com/p/as3svgrendererlib/)

Hopes that helps